# Android Studio RecyclerView item width within custom Layout

Tags: android, android-studio

I am creating a custom `Layout` to use within my `RecyclerView`, the only thing I can't figure out is how to set the width of a list item within my custom layout. 
Because every list item has a different width.

Comment: You can probably keep the width of the list items as `wrap_content`. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: The width of the list item is based on the data that i get within the adapter, so wrap_content isn't going to work

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Recycler.ViewHolder in your custom Adapter, you could build a class to extend this ViewHolder like

```
   /**view halper class for recycler list item*/
public class MyViewHelper extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvtitle,tvdesc,tvtown,tvtype;
    public ImageView thumbnail;
    RelativeLayout rl;

    public MyViewHelper (View view) {
        super(view);
        tvtitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvtitle);
        tvdesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvdesc);
        tvtown = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvtown);
        tvtype = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvtype);
        thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        rl = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rlClick);
    }
}
```

In oncreateview you could create and return this view

```
   View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.offer_swap_cardview, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHelper(itemView);
```

This enables you to get view items in onBindView and you could change their heights accordingly

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {    
MyViewHolder myholder= (MyViewHolder)holder;
myholder.tvtitle.setWidth(30);//in pixels

}
```